# express file upload error and several problems

Tags: node.js, express

I am using multiparty to handle file upload.

In my controller, I have

```
exports.uploadFile = function(req, res, next) {

    if (req.files && req.files.file) {
        var file = req.files.file
        var tmpPath = file.path
        var targetDirectory = dir.public + '/upload'
        var targetPath = dir.public + '/upload' + '/' + file.name

        if (file.size > config.uploadFileMaxSize) {
            fs.unlink(tmpPath, function(err) {
                if (err)
                    return next(err)
                return next(helper.getAbuseError('file is too large'))
            })
        }
        else {
            fs.mkdir(targetDirectory, function(err) {
                if (err && err.code !== 'EEXIST')
                    return next(err)
                fs.rename(tmpPath, targetPath, function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        return next(err)
                    fs.unlink(tmpPath, function(err) {
                        if (err)
                            return next(err)
                        return res.json(helper.dataAppendedWithMessage({path: targetPath}, 'success', 'file uploaded'))
                    })
                })
            })
        }

    }
}
```

In my router:

```
restRouter.post(helper.serverUrl.common.uploadFile,
    helper.permission.middleware(helper.accessList.uploadFile),
    multiparty(), //Note: only used in file uploads
    commonController.uploadFile)
```

There are several problems.

1. unable to mkdir. the error breaks at unlink

   ENOENT, unlink    '/var/folders/5p/qqz2vyhd3yqb_334h6fj7_y00000gq/T/O3BTOo3rXdKRT3Zfs5JPUpn8.png'
2. Why is the above tmpPath under `/var/folders` ? from all the tutorial I read, it should be stored under `[app_root]/tmp`
3. Besides checking for file sizes, how do i only allow images, audios and videos? I need to support all the types that can be embedded in  and   tag, and reject everything else. I know there is a `file.type` value but I dont want to hard code it. How can i check if a file type can be used in HTML5 tags?
4. In my success callback, I send back `{path: targetPath}` for client  tag to use. But the targetPath is `/path/to/app_root/public/upload/xxx.png`, how can I only send back `/public/upload/xxx.png`? I can of course search for `public` and strip off `/path/to/app_root/` But the code will get messy. is there other elegant ways to do that?
5. is it possible to reject large file earlier? this function is only called after the file is stored at `/tmp`, the attacker can easily flood my storage by simply uploading a 1000GB file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are several answers:

1. `fs.rename()` renames a file from A to B, it doesn't copy the file. So after a successful rename, path A doesn't exist anymore, so you can't (/don't have to) unlink it;
2. Not sure why this happens. `/var/folders/XXX/YYY/T` contains *"per-user temporary files and caches"* (see `$ man hier`), but Multiparty uses `os.tmpDir()` which at least on my Mac returns `/tmp` (as expected);
3. In short: you can't, unless you can find a module that will provide those types and I doubt it exists. You can probably check the content-type against `image/*`, `video/*` and `audio/*`, though;
4. I think you still need to do it manually:

   ```
   var filePath   = '/upload/' + file.name;
   var targetPath = dir.public + filePath;
   ...
   res.json({ path: filePath });
   ```
5. Any options you pass to `connect-multiparty` will be passed to `multiparty` under the hood, which has [`maxFilesSize`](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty#multipartyform) option. This will limit the upload of *all* files to a certain limit, but if you're only uploading just one file it should work too;

Comment: on my mac it returns `/var/folders`. is it mac configuration or express configuration?

Comment: i am not using `node-multiparty`. I am using `connect-multiparty`. Also, the multiparty middleware is invoked *after* user uploaded file to `/tmp`. How can you prevent that inside the middleware?

Comment: `connect-multiparty` uses `node-multiparty`, and _also_ takes care of the file upload handling. As for the temp dir: are you using the official Node.js or did you install using Homebrew? Perhaps the difference is related to that.

Comment: i use homebrew to install it

Comment: @OMGPOP it might be related to that. If you really want to use `/tmp`, set the [`uploadDir`](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty#multipartyform) option.

Comment: can i get a custom callback if exceed maxFilesSize for connect multiparty? I want to send back a json object

Comment: I don't think `multiparty` has that (please read the fine manual to make sure), but [`busboy`](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy#busboy-special-events) does.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you a function may be this could help you to upload the file Though I have Done it for image uploading but with little modification this may work for you too..

```
    handleFileUpload: function(req) {

            if(!req.files || !req.files.place_img || !req.files.place_img.name) {
                return req.body.currentPicture || '';
            }
            var data = fs.readFileSync(req.files.place_img.path);
            var fileName = req.files.place_img.name;
            var uid = crypto.randomBytes(10).toString('hex');
            var dir = __dirname +"/../public/uploads/" + uid;
            fs.mkdirSync(dir, '0777');
            fs.writeFileSync(dir + "/" + fileName, data);
            return '/uploads/' + uid + "/" + fileName;
}
```

Comment: why do you use readFileSync? do you need to catch exception in that case?

Comment: i dont see any difference between our code except for the async